# How Do I Disable a set of checkboxes using a button?

Tags: html

I have this HTML code that I'm writing for an app that I like to call Ceremony Script Generator. On the Wedding Ceremony Builder section of this app, there's a page I'm writing about extra ceremonies. However, I'm having trouble building a button that says, "Disable These". I want to make it a toggle button, but I'm not sure how to do this with HTML code. Here's the code I have so far. Tell me if this looks right to you. How shall I send the code?

Comment: Hi Annabelle, I'm sure we can help you better if you show us your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How shall I send the code?

To share the code just use
3 times "`" before and after the code...

like

````
it must be written like this :

```
<div>
    <p>This parrot is pining for the fjords</p>
</div>
```
````

Comment: Here's the code I've written so far. Tell me if this looks right to you.

Comment: ```
<html>
<head>
<title>Step 6</title>
</head>
       <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="checkbox">
         <input value="plantingCeremony" name="optionalCeremonies" type="checkbox">
         Tree-Planting
        </label>
       </div>
      </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="checkbox">
         <input value="dancingCeremony" name="optionalCeremonies" type="checkbox">
         Didgeridoo Circle
        </label>
       </div>
<button aria-pressed="false">
  Disable These
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Edit Your question instead. Code is not displayed correctly in comments.
Thank You. @Annabelle

Comment: I tried your script and button, but it won't do anything. How do I send the full file so you can look and see what I wrote?

Comment: Sorry, It works on all my browsers here...
Did you tried to copy and paste the code on a test page???
It should uncheck all the selected items

Comment: Yes, and it actually works on Microsoft Edge. However, my screenreader won't announce that "Disable These" is a "toggle button", despite the fact that it's actually labeled as a button. Isn't that strange?

Answer (score 0):

@Annabelle , You may try this :)

It works like a charm here.
Let me know...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Step 6</title>
    <script>
        function disableCheckBoxes(){
            var elmnts = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for (var i=0; i < elmnts.length; i++) {
                elmnts[i].checked=false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input name="optionalCeremonies" type="checkbox" value="plantingCeremony">
                Tree-Planting
            </label>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input name="optionalCeremonies" type="checkbox" value="dancingCeremony">
                Didgeridoo Circle
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input name="optionalCeremonies" type="checkbox" value="spam1">
                Eat spam and bacon
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input name="optionalCeremonies" type="checkbox" value="parrot1">
                Buy a parrot
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input name="optionalCeremonies" type="checkbox" value="pining">
                Pining for the fjords
            </label>
        </div>
        <button aria-pressed="false" onClick="javascript:disableCheckBoxes()">
            Disable These
        </button>
</body>
</html>
```